# xdotool Desktop issue

Tags: .desktop, xdotool

I am very new to this, so I hope not to offend. 
I am trying to create Desktop.desktop icons for my HTPC (Home theatre PC). Each icon, once pressed should open the URL and maximise the screen. My code below does it, but the xdotool does not maximise. However, when i run my xdotool on a terminal, works! I assume the code needs some sort of delay between opening the URL and maximising?

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=YouTube
Type=Link
URL=https://www.youtube.com/
Comment Terminal=false
Icon=/home/babak/Myicons/YouTube.png
Exec=xdotool search "google chrome" windowactivate --sync key F11
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is this exactly how your current .desktop file looks? I do not see the command to open the URL. In a .desktop file, you cannot include multiple commands. Work via a script that you call in the .desktop file, or use a command such as `sh -c " command 1 ; command 2"`

Comment: I see. There is the URL=line, which is what opens the browser at the indicated URL. Because of that, the Exec= line is not executed. Perhaps if you put the Exec= line earlier, then that will be executed, bit then not the URL line. You will need to remove the URL line and 1) open the URL and 2) maximize the window. I will post an answer.

Comment: Hi Vanadium, Yes it does open the URL. I assume the post interpreter for a [Desktop] knows its a Link type, and has a URL. Not sure why you have difficulty with that. I assumed a [Desktop] is a type of special script that will be interpreted into one. Btw, I have already tried putting the xdotool in a sh script and called it within the [Desktop]. Same result. I assume once interpreted both methods yield the same binay.

Comment: I posted an answer that should make things clear.

Comment: @vanadium. Thanks for your answer. I did eventually managed to solve the issue using one of your suggestions. I created a [Name].desktop, within it I ran an execute statement running a bash. Within the bash I ran the following:

google-chrome
xdotool search --sync --onlyvisible "google chrome"
xdotool key F11

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A .desktop file will either open an URL, or run a command, but not both at the same time. To have it open the URL and do something with the created windows, combine both actions in the `exec =` line.

There are two ways you can combine two actions on an `Exec =` line.

1. Pass multiple commands to your shell using a construct such as `sh -c "command 1; command 2". This is a way to pass two commands through a single command: an`Exec=` line handles only a single command.
2. Create a bash script containing the needed commands, and call that bash script in your `Exec=` line.

Thus, delete the line `URL=`, and change the `Exec=` line to

```
sh -c 'google-chrome https://www.youtube.com/ && xdotool search "google chrome" windowactivate --sync key F11'
```

You can replace `sh` by `bash`. Instead of `&&` you could also use `;`, but the former will make sure the `xdotool` command is only executed if the first command is executed successfully.

If there is a timing issue, then try inserting a pauze, e.g.

```
...&& sleep 0.3 && xdotool
```

would wait for 0.3 seconds before executing `xdotool`. `xdotool` also has a build-in sleep command, so `&& xdotool sleep 0.3 search` should also do the trick.

Comment: Thanks for your comment Vanadium. Tried both with and without the delay. Same result as before plus a few error comments. Did you try this on a terminal yourself? thx

Comment: It doesn't work because of the quotes around `"google chrome"`. Escape them: `sh -c "google-chrome https://www.youtube.com/ && xdotool search \"google chrome\" windowactivate --sync key F11"`.

Comment: Not too sure what you mean Danzel. Tried your statement, also doesn't work. Lots of messages. Could you try it out and see if it works? thx

Comment: Indeed, there is an issue with the quotes. I placed single quotes around the entire command. Can you try and provide feedback?

Comment: So there is another problem. If no instance of chrome is running, the `google-chrome` call doesn't return until chrome is terminated (and the instance is a child process of `sh`). You can work around this by using `xdg-open [URL]` instead of calling chrome directly. Also, there is an additional `--sync` missing directly after `--search`.

Comment: That are indeed other problems than the specific issue asked. It would probably make more sense to use wmctrl to directy maximize the window, or even better: google-chrome appears to have the --kiosk option to have it start full screen.

Comment: Indeed, there is an issue with the quotes. I placed single quotes around the entire command. Can you try and provide feedback?   [Tried, same]

Comment: danzel, thanks for your input, but does not work.

Comment: Vanadium, thanks for your suggestions. The --kiost option is interesting, but I need to solve the issue here directly, or know that is undoable for reasons i can test and understand. Cheers